# Problema instalación cliente Oracle Swap Size Servidor RedHat

Tags: linux, oracle-11g, rhel, vmware

Actualmente tengo un servidor virtual con RedHat 6.4 de 64bits en VMWare. Al momento de crearlo le asignamos 6 GB de RAM y posteriormente se le modificó por la interfaz de VMWare para aumentarlo hasta 8 GB (ya fue reiniciado), pero al tratar de instalar el cliente de Oracle 11gR2, me muestra una cantidad menor a 6 GB en Swap Size.

¿Cómo hago para aumentar esta memoria?

Adjunto una imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al validar la información que está teniendo el servidor obtengo lo siguiente:

```
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        8061076 kB
MemFree:          200740 kB
Buffers:          259300 kB
Cached:          4409424 kB
SwapCached:            8 kB
Active:          3694088 kB
Inactive:        3803428 kB
Active(anon):    2530112 kB
Inactive(anon):  1147684 kB
Active(file):    1163976 kB
Inactive(file):  2655744 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       6111224 kB
SwapFree:        6111216 kB
Dirty:                44 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2828784 kB
Mapped:           946752 kB
Shmem:            849004 kB
Slab:             243648 kB
SReclaimable:     209000 kB
SUnreclaim:        34648 kB
KernelStack:        4328 kB
PageTables:        39360 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    10141760 kB
Committed_AS:    4130892 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      158668 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359573228 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   2467840 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       10240 kB
DirectMap2M:     8378368 kB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución en un foro, la dejo por aquí si ayuda a alguien más. [Solución](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/how-to-add-swap-space/?utm_source=feedburner)

Seguir pasos con usuario **root**:

1. Crea un archivo para la memoria swap con el nombre "myswapfile", en el directorio /root con tamaño de 1024 MB (1GB)

   dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/myswapfile bs=1M count=1024

   ls -l /root/myswapfile
2. Cambio de permisos para que solo el root pueda tener acceso a modificarlo

   chmod 600 /root/myswapfile
3. Hace que el archivo myswapfile sirva como archivo swap reconocido por el sistema

   mkswap /root/myswapfile
4. Activa el swap con ese archivo

   swapon /root/myswapfile
5. Para terminar de configurarlo como swap se agrega la siguiente línea a este archivo /etc/fstab:

   /root/myswapfile               swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
6. Verificar que se creó y está siendo reconocido

   swapon -s

   free -k
7. Si no quieres reiniciar, para asegurarte de que el sistema toma toda la memoria swap, incluyendo la nueva:

   swapoff -a

   swapon -a